# VS Code automatically deleting internal spaces on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make some statements visually line-up on the equal signs (per company style), which requires me putting extra spaces inside the line.

However, when I press save, VS Code deletes the spaces: even though I have all extensions off, and have it set to show all whitespace.

[clip of problem, jump is on save](https://i.imgur.com/HJ8iXzl.mp4)

Any clue what might be causing this? I've tried restarting, toggling all the whitespace settings, disabling all extensions; no luck.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>comma</kbd>
- add line:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```

You can also exclude some file types from format on save if you don't want to turn format on save off:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: I still think it's valuable to have format on save in my workspace, though. Is there a way to change how it formats?

Comment: @soph_iest I don't think so, but you can exclude some file types. Updated the answer.